# Extracting n-grams as words from strings in Perl

Tags: perl, n-gram

Is there a module or Perl code that extract n-grams of words from a string besides `Text::Ngrams`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there seem to be [several](http://search.cpan.org/search?q=ngram;s=0).